# Power BI - DAX - Add 30 minutes to a measure created by DateDiff

Tags: powerbi, dax

I created the following measure and would like to add 30 minutes to it. How can I do it?

```
Worked Time Each Day = DATEDIFF([Clinician Min Time Per Day],[Clinician Max Time Per Day],MINUTE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can you DateAdd function to add 30 minutes to your max time

```
DateAdd([Clinician Max Time Per Day], 30, Minutes )
```

Substitute this in you measure of datediff where you are using max time